# Table row colors overlapping column background color

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Sorry for the poor title description. I have columns of dates, with the current date having a specific background color which is applied from top down. The issue I am facing is that my stripped rows are overlapping it. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

[table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpC8m.png)

```
#js
    $(function () {
        $("#my-table td").filter(":nth-child(" + (idx) + ")")
            .css("background-color", 'rgba(194, 204, 214, 0.6)')
    })
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: my guess would be that the styles on the horizontally coloured rows have higher "importance" in your css than the initial coloured column has. See [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74073211/edit) to include an example of the relevant HTML.